# how to get relations (family relatives) in dataset?

Tags: postgresql

I have a database with the following fields:

```
name, father_name, grand_name, last_name
```

I want to view family relatives from the database

i.e records with same `last_name` and `d1.grand_name = d2.father_name`

How to write this query ?

Comment: Simply create `relations` table and store there the type of relationship between any 2 people (e.g. uncle, aunt, 1st cousin, 2nd cousin, etc.) Keep in mind that in most cases the name of relationship depends on who is the left side person and who is the right side one. You can also include a column `distance` where you can store the blood distance between the 2 people.

Comment: Could you add a data sample and the expected result?